# Egit push doesn't change files in remote repository

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

I came to know about the **git / egit  version control system** last week, seems too good to be true .So thought to shift from **SVN** to git..Since last week I am trying to understand the basics and concepts of **git**.

So I created a test environment for understanding the workflow of **egit** in **eclipse** as following.

I am following the strategy of remote tracking there are two repositories named local and remote used for understanding the workflow.

1. I created a repository named 'remote' with an emtpy index.php file and has one master branch and imported the project into eclipse.
2. I created another git repository named `'local'` by cloning the above `'remote' git repo`, this repository is now tracked by `'remote'` repository has one master branch and origin/master remote tracking branch.
3. I imported the project from `'local' git repo`. into my eclipse workbench and changed the `index.php` file using eclipse php editor **->** committed changes to local's master branch and **->** performed push from local master branch.
4. When checking the remote working directory .. there is no change updated which I did in local's `index.php` file , however master branch in the remote repository view shows the latest commit which I committed in the local's master branch, but unfortunately files are not updated, it just adds asterisk mark to all changed files in my remote project view.

So researching about the asterisk mark I found its in staged condition .So can anyone lead me to the right way explaining how to successfully perform **push operation** from local's master branch to remote's branch I will be grateful.

this is the picture of my **egit test case** set up in **eclipse** for understanding the workflow. you can see the **asterisk mark** in the remote project after performing push from local repository,you can see all three branches **viz.local's master**, **origin/master** and **remote's master** branches shows same latest commit.

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/av2ktmjfr/egit_test.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Me6S.png)

Thank You.

Comment: You pushed to a remote that had a working directory?  That doesn't automatically do a merge on the working directory--it's analogous to only doing a fetch from remote to local.

Comment: @nitind So you mean I have to create a bare repository for remote tracking without working directory and one more thing I wanted to ask.. - setting up remote project in the same workspace does that cause problem?

Comment: I think it's supposed to be bare, and I don't understand the second part.

Comment: If it is supposed to be bare, it means remote repo. will not have working directory it will have only branch.. so what if other user want to clone through the remote repository?.. I tried using bare repo. as a remote ,when I push from changes from local to remote, I don't find any files in remote repo. just branch gets updated with the latest commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using bare repo. as a remote, when I push from changes from local to remote, I don't find any files in remote repo. Just branch gets updated with the latest commit.

That seems normal, since a *bare* repo has **no working tree*, meaning no files.

You would need to clone that remote repo, and add this cloned repo (non-bare) as a project in your Eclipse, in order to:

- push from your first Egit-managed repo to the bare remote repo
- pull from that same bare repo to your second Egit-managed non-bare repo.

Comment: thanks bro. that was good explanation ..I got it. Create a base bare master repo. used only for tracking and cloning -> other users can clone this repo and import projects from the cloned repo. and commit to master bare report. really thanks for explanation