# Issues with having Eclipse write to a remote git repository

Tags: git, eclipse

So I have run into an issue where I have setup my Eclipse installation to push config files to a remote git repository (a remote repository on a local linux server).  Now, when I change, *add* or update a file, I am able to save the file, *commit* the file and then *push* the file to the remote git repo with no issues. However, when I look at the remote repo, the updated file is not showing any changes and the time stamp does not update.  When I run `git status`, I see that the file has changed and is waiting on being committed on the remote git repo. This was working before but I am not sure what happened to cause the behavior to change.

I have re-imported the remote repo into eclipse, I have tried to make sure that everything was synced up and tried to push the changes again and I am still seeing a commit in place on the remote repo. I have tried to clean the repo, run an fsck on the repo, I have tried to resync the repo, and of course I have tried to pull the repo many times to get everything in sync.  I have even gone as far as restoring the remote repo to a date where I know the repo behaved as expected, pulled and rebased the repo, but the behavior is still the same.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Thanks!

Comment: And you are really do a `git commit -m "commit message"` and after them `git pull`?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure.  I am running a commit and push via eclipse, and to be honest, I am not sure where in eclipse to check to see what commands are being run with a commit and push.

Comment: I don't know anything about Eclipse... But I would open the terminal in Eclipse ([How to open terminal inside Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623643/how-to-open-terminal-inside-eclipse)) and type in `git log`. There you can see which changes have already been pushed to remote. Otherwise you can also `git commit -m "commit-message"` and after `git push`. It may be that git doesn't push correctly to the remote repositor in Eclipse...

Comment: These questions (answers) from *stackoverflow* could possibly help: [egit-push-doesnt-change-files-in-remote-repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620704/egit-push-doesnt-change-files-in-remote-repository) and [when-using-eclipse-and-egit-i-can-not-push-to-upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351304/when-using-eclipse-and-egit-i-can-not-push-to-upstream)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am going through those links now.

Comment: Maybe you just looking on the wrong (remote) branches. How have you configure your local branch (in the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the branch and choose _Configure Branch..._). When also using the command line Git (which is not required by Eclipse), hit _Refresh_ in the _Git Stagging_ view to get the changes done outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out howlger.  I actually backed up the old local branch, and re-cloned the branch from the remote back to eclipse just to make sure that I was grabbing the correct branch.  I am still trying to find the magic bullet but what SwissCodeMen was able to share brings me to believe the issue is on my local eclipse config.